# Evaluate formula from another cell (without equal (=) character (NO VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Cell A1 contains very long formula without "="
How can I evaluate formula in A2?

NO VBA

P.S.: formula from A1 is really very long:

`TEXTJOIN(", ";;IF(INDIRECT("E"&AA2&":E"&AB2)=INDIRECT("AA"&ROW());INDIRECT("B"&AA2&":B"&AB2);""))`

I tried to use INDIRECT function, but evaluated response was an error "#REF!"

Comment: If that is the formula, then it is not that long... So put = in front.

Answer (score 1):

So ms365 has a neat way of using the ancient XLM Macro `EVALUATE()` function if one would call this through the named manager. For example, create a named formula called 'z' and refer to:

```
=LAMBDA(x,EVALUATE(x))
```

If you play around a little you'd notice that you can refer to all sorts of written formulae in string format, for example `=z("TEXTJOIN("", "",,B3:B6)")` given the screenshot would return `1, 2, 3, 4`. This holds true for a lot of cases, but not when `INDIRECT()` is used in the mix. You'll recieve (at least in my testing) a '#REF' error. I believe I read somewhere that `EVALUATE()` will simply error out trying to parse a string holding `INDIRECT()`, I'm unsure if this holds true though. I'll update my answer if I find some more info. Untill then, I used a formula to bypass this problem:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(x,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"INDIRECT(","ζ"),TAKE(REDUCE(VSTACK(x,0),SEQUENCE(LEN(x)),LAMBDA(y,n,LET(r,TAKE(y,1),s,DROP(y,1),q,MID(r,n,1),SWITCH(q,"ζ",VSTACK(r,1),"(",IF(s,VSTACK(r,s+1),y),")",IF(s-1,VSTACK(r,s-1),VSTACK(REPLACE(r,n,1,"ξ"),0)),y)))),1))
```

The idea behind this formula is simple, however the execution is rather tricky, and I'm unsure if it's robust enough. I wanted to look for balanced paranthesis after each occurence of `INDIRECT(`, hence the use of `VSTACK()` inside `REDUCE()` to allow for a 'ticker'. Once all the appropriate paranthesis are swapped out for other identifiable characters, we could use our formula in `C1`:

```
=z(LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(B1,"ζ","ξ"),b,TEXTJOIN(IFERROR(MAP(DROP(a,,1),LAMBDA(c,z(c))),""),,TAKE(a,,1)),b))
```

Here we split by the identified characters, take the 2nd column (each substring within the correct paranthesis of the `INDIRECT()` functions), throw each value in our 'z' function, then simply `TEXTJOIN()` the 1st column back with the delimiters we found through 'z' and finally we chuck the resulting string into our 'z' function one more time.

You could create the whole thing in a single go too:

```
=z(LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(@LET(x,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"INDIRECT(","ζ"),TAKE(REDUCE(VSTACK(x,0),SEQUENCE(LEN(x)),LAMBDA(y,n,LET(r,TAKE(y,1),s,DROP(y,1),q,MID(r,n,1),SWITCH(q,"ζ",VSTACK(r,1),"(",IF(s,VSTACK(r,s+1),y),")",IF(s-1,VSTACK(r,s-1),VSTACK(REPLACE(r,n,1,"ξ"),0)),y)))),1)),"ζ","ξ"),b,TEXTJOIN(IFERROR(MAP(DROP(a,,1),LAMBDA(c,z(c))),""),,TAKE(a,,1)),b))
```

There you go. Evaluated your formula without VBA. However, do you wish to save your workbook, the Excel 4.0 function stored in the defined name would require you to choose a macro-enabled file type.